# How to filter a number starts with special number

Tags: excel

I want to filter the numbers which are starting from  7 , from the given data set. I tried using filter->custom auto filter->begins with 7.  Then it will display only few numbers, but there are more phone numbers begins with 7.

Comment: Can you give more details concerning your question, please?

Comment: I have 100,000 data set containing phone numbers. I want to filter the phone numbers which are starting with number 7 and then select there category as mobile

Comment: I tried to use custom auto filter and filter for begins with  numbers 7. But that gives only 20 odd phone numbers out of the whole list.

Comment: I can't see what were the Excel developers were thinking when they implemented Custom Filters to behave this way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're identically formatted you can do `=left(X#,1)` in another column where `X#` is the cell you're looking at. Then fill this formula down and sort by this new column.

Comment: Thats work for me. By using a filter to new coloum i was able to filter numbers starting from 7.